# How do I discard modified content in git submodules?

Tags: git, git-submodules

I recently ran a git submodule `init` and `update` commits in my staging branch. This led to git downloading a bunch of changes from submodules that I do not want to put into staging and wish to discard completely.

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
  (commit or discard the untracked or modified content in submodules)
        modified:   path-to/submodule1 (modified content)
        modified:   path-to/submodule2 (new commits,modified content)
    …


no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
```

I'd like to discard all of these changes and and not add anything to my current branch. How do I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since each submodule is its own Git repo, you can reset each one individually.

1. Get rid of any local changes that are not committed: go into each submodule, and run `git reset --hard`
2. Make sure each submodule is on the commit that the top-level Git repo wants, by running `git submodule update` at the top level.